# Can opencv's FaceRecognizer mean replace image database?

Tags: c++, opencv, face-recognition

If you have 100 pictures of faces in a database for each classification such as age or gender, would it make sense to load in all the pictures for each classification at a time and train the facerecognizer model, save the mean image, then load in only the mean images for each classification to train the facerecognizer model with?

We have about 50,000 face images in our database, and so i've tried training the model with them, but got an out of memory exception. So i converted the application to 64 bits, just so i can train the model and save the model to a file so i'd only have to load in the images once, but its been a couple hours now that the model is being trained with the images, and the ram usage is over 10gb and still going up slowly, i'm afraid i'll run out of memory again before it finishes training, which is why i was hoping i could just get the mean image for each classification.

Comment: do you really have to load all images at once?

Comment: well, thats the thing, because its algorithmically impossible to update the fisherface or eigenface models, and the fisherface model is the one that should be used for things like emotion or age classification, so yeah, as far as i understand they need to be loaded in at once to train the model. If i were to try training it again after its already been trained, it loses all previous training

Comment: sorry, to be more clear, loading in all the images is not actually a problem, they only come to about 400mb once loaded. Its whatever opencv is doing behind the scene with this data thats causing such huge memory consumption